# Modifying colours in javascript

Tags: javascript, rgba

I am using some javascript that I found online, which changes the colour of a webpage as the horizontal scroll position changes. Code below:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    checkScroll = setInterval(function(){scrollHorizontal()},10);
  });

function scrollHorizontal() {
  maxScroll = $('.meh').width() - $('body').width();
  scrolledHor = $(window).scrollLeft();
  backgroundOpacity = 'rgba(0,0,0,'+(scrolledHor / maxScroll)+')';
  $('body').css('background',backgroundOpacity);
  $('.pixels').html('Scrolled: '+scrolledHor+' pixels');

}
```

As the page slowly turns black, the black text becomes invisible, so I had the idea of changing the colour of the text from black to while as the page scrolls as well. To do this, I modified the code to have two extra lines of code, as well as the appropriate css. See below:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    checkScroll = setInterval(function(){scrollHorizontal()},10);
  });

function scrollHorizontal() {
  maxScroll = $('.meh').width() - $('body').width();
  scrolledHor = $(window).scrollLeft();

  backgroundOpacity = 'rgba(0,0,0,'+(scrolledHor / maxScroll)+')';
  $('body').css('background',backgroundOpacity);

  textOpacity = 'rgba((255/maxScroll)*scrolledHor,(255/maxScroll)*scrolledHor,(255/maxScroll)*scrolledHor),1';
  $('table').css('color',textOpacity);

  $('.pixels').html('Scrolled: '+scrolledHor+' pixels');

}
```

This doesnt seem to be working though. I assume its something to do with the syntax that I am using but I have never used Javascript before so not sure what I am doing wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: Something to do with the values being int not str maybe? Do I need to do something like: str(255/maxScroll)*scrolledHor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!

```
  co255 = (255/maxScroll)*scrolledHor;
  textOpacity = 'rgba('+co255+','+co255+','+co255+',1)';
```